# Security risk at ssh tunnel relay

Tags: networking, ssh, security, encryption, proxy

I'm trying to use services such as ngrok/telebit to be able to access my personal web server outside my local network.

The web server contains a lot of sensitive data and I'm concerned about the security risk involved in using an MITM proxy such as ngrok/telebit.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614266/1494559) by [coolaj86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151312/coolaj86), it appears that there is decryption done at the relay.

1. I would like to understand what happens at the proxy/relay/jumphost when forwarding traffic.
2. Does decryption happen at the relay both for ssh and https traffic?
3. Why is it that some ssh-proxy services require you to provide the `-J` ssh option and ngrok doesn't require this?

Telebit seems to provide the end-to-end encryption (without decryption at the relay) but requires specifying proxy command and this is not possible when using ssh through a phone/tablet app.

Of course, all these issues could be overcome by paying for premium tier ssh apps or a premium ngrok tier but I want something that is in free-tier for my initial prototyping -- a setup to tunnel ssh/sftp and https with end-to-end encryption without using advanced (in-app premium) ssh options such as proxy command, etc.

Comment: "I want something that is in free-tier for my initial prototyping". Why should a company give you something for free without downsides? And the safest way is to pay your ISP to give you a public IP address, then you can set up your own security infrastructure for remote access to your home network, and be **sure** it is safe.

Comment: If you use ssh port forwarding the https traffic is encrypted twice inside the ssh tunnel and outside only one time (the https encryption).